# BASH to pipe find output and check if it exists elsewhere

Tags: bash, if-statement, find

I am trying to identify files in a directory that are not symlinks, and then check that the same filenames exists in another directory.

In my script below, it works for when find identifies only one file, but fails when there is more than one.

This is what i have:

```
FILENAME=`find /home/user/test1/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \! -type l -printf "%f\n"`
if [ ! -f /home/user/test2/"$FILENAME" ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```

out put of `echo $FILENAME`

```
test.touch touch.2
```

FURTHER DETAILS:

directory structure

```
 /dir1     /dir2
 filea     filea
 fileb     fileb
 filec     filed
 symlinke  symlinke   
           symlinkf
```

In the above file structure, I need the script to stop if it finds that `filec` is not in `dir1`. If `dir1` and `dir2` match, then the script should continue.

What I want is to see if there are any non-symlink files in the directory `dir1`, that do not appear in `dir2` - and then **STOP** my script if it finds missing files.

Comment: Why would you expect `if [ ! -f /home/user/test2/"$FILENAME" ]` to work when filename contains *multiple files*? Why not `for i in /home/user/test1/*; do if [ ! -h "$i" ]; then ....`?

Comment: A point on terminology.  Every entry in a directory is a link.  Some of the links in the directory are links to files which are symbolic links.  Some of the entries are links to regular files.  I believe you are using the word "link" to mean "symbolic link", but the two terms are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot test multiple files within the `test` (e.g. `[...]`) builtin at once. Your script is equivalent to

```
if [ ! -f /home/user/test2/"test.touch touch.2" ]
```

That will never work because the file `/home/user/test2/"test.touch touch.2"` does not exist. If you want to test each non-symlink file, you can do

```
for i in /home/user/test1/*; do 
    if [ ! -h "$i" ]; then
        echo "do something with non-link '$i'"
    fi
done
```

You can use `find` as well and use *process substitution* in bash, e.g.

```
while read -r file; do
    echo "do something with non-link '$file'"
done < <(find /home/user/test1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Either way is fine.

---

Update pursuant to your edit you could do:

```
for i in /dir1/*; do 
    if [ ! -h "$i" ]; then
        [ -f "/dir2/${i##*/}" ] && echo "/dir2/${i##*/} exists!"
    fi
done
```

or with `find`

```
while read -r file; do
    [ -f "/dir2/${file##*/}" ] && echo "/dir2/${file##*/} exists!"
done < <(find /dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Let me know if that is what you were after.

---

Here is a specific example using your data based on our last discussion in the comments:

**Directory Layout**

```
$  tree
.
├── bar
├── dir1
│   ├── filea
│   ├── fileb
│   ├── filec
│   └── symlinke -> ../foo
├── dir2
│   ├── filea
│   ├── fileb
│   ├── filed
│   ├── symlinke -> ../foo
│   └── symlinkf -> ../bar
└── foo
```

**Example Using `for` Loop**

```
$ for i in dir1/*; do 
>     if [ ! -h "$i" ]; then 
>         [ -f "dir2/${i##*/}" ] && echo "dir2/${i##*/} exists!"
>     fi
> done
dir2/filea exists!
dir2/fileb exists!
```

**Example With `find`**

```
$ while read -r i; do  
>     [ -f "dir2/${i##*/}" ] && echo "dir2/${i##*/} exists!"
> done < <(find dir1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
dir2/filea exists!
dir2/fileb exists!
```

It's my understanding that is what you are after, if you are still having trouble, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: thanks for the reply. maybe i am not reading this correctly, but your suggestion does not do what i need. i.e. find non-links in a directory, and check that those filenames exist in a different directory.

Comment: @jakethedog Both suggestions find *non-link* files in `/home/user/test2/`. What you want to compare them to and how you want to react is a bit unclear. If you clarify, I'm happy to help further. That's why I specifically left `do something with non-link` as an indication of where you would perform your needed actions. (I did have a copy/paste error in the find `echo` statement `:)`

Comment: If you want to check if they exist in say `/path/to/dir2` you can add in place of the `echo` a simple test `[ -f "/path/to/dir2/${i##*/}" ] && echo "/path/to/dir2/${i##*/} exists!"`

Comment: OK, looks like I read you mind anyway. Just remember to use `${i##*/}` with the `for` example and `${file##*/}` with the `find` example.

Comment: this seems really close, but it is not quite right. for one thing the echo prints all the files in dir3 no matter what, even if they don't exist in dir1. the real problem is that my script does not stop when there is a missing filename. i have tried the pure BASH and the find version, and I couldn't make it work. i have tried with `set -e` and `&&`. could you add that part for me so I get it right? to rephrase, the script should stop if there are filenames (non-symlinks) in dir1 that are not in dir2

Comment: If you are saying you have additional directories below `dir1` (e.g. `dir1/dir3` and do not want to process anything for any subdirectories when using the for loop, just modify your test, e.g. `[ ! -d "$I" -a ! -h "$i" ]` to add a *not directory* test. The `while` approach using `find` will not exhibit that behavior due to the `-type f` option that limits the results to *files only* and `-maxdepth 1` limits traversal to the first level. Let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: Sorry, no. There are only two directories to test. Or, rather, there is one directory to test - `dir1` against `dir2` - but I don't care about what is in `dir2` except that the filenames on non-symlinked files in `dir1` appear in `dir2`

Comment: Here is where I'm confused. Both the `for` and `while` implementations will only output the names in `dir2` that are also present in `dir1` and not symlinks. That's the only thing that can happen. In your example, only `filea` and `fileb` would be output. You are sure your links are softlinks (`ln -s target linkname`) and not hardlinks, right?

Comment: @jakethedog Take a look at my last addition to the answer and let me know if that is correct based on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for your extensive help on this. the example that you provide behaves correctly in identifying matching files, ignoring symlinks. what i need it to do is to **STOP** when it does not match `filec` in `dir2`.
for example:


`set -e`
`for i in dir1/*; do`
`if [ ! -h "$i" ]; then`
`[ -f "dir2/${i##*/}" ] && echo "dir2/${i##*/} exists!"`
`fi`
`done`
`touch ./scriptcontinues.test`

if `filec` is not found in `dir2` then the script should not execute the remainder of the script, in this example, the `touch` command

Comment: Oh, that's easy -- whew!, just add `|| break` after `exists!"` `:)` but... be careful, that will cause it to exit after the *first* failure to match a file in the `Dir2`, not the *last*.

Comment: by having `...  exists!" || break` it does indeed only show the first `dir2/filea exists!` when `filec` is missing, but it continues to run the rest of the script that is after the `done` which is what i want to stop.

Comment: Do you want to stop the `loop` or `exit` the script? `break` jumps out of the loop, but does not exit the script (so anything after the loop still executes). If you want to exit, then use `exit 0` instead of `break`.

Comment: Note, there are other ways to do that as well. One is to set `nomatch=0` flag before you enter the loop. Then if a match fails, you can set `nomatch=1` (instead of `break` or `exit`). After the loop exists, you can control what happens next with a simple `if [ "$nomatch" -eq '1' ]; then ...handle as needed...`. That's another alternative to `exit`.

Comment: i think that is it. i was trying with `exit 1` - thanks for your help. apologies if it was confusing at times.

Comment: Glad you are getting it working. See my last comment for one more suggestion. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: hi again, just a quick follow up question. can you help me with the correct syntax for `${i##*/}` that will capture directory names? thanks

Comment: Sure, `${i%/*}`. That will trim everything *from the right* up to and including the *first* `'/'` encountered. It's simple. In parameter expansion `'#'` means from the *left* and `'%`' means from the *right*. Two of them, e.g. `##` mean trim to the last occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of bash parameters, but I think I found my problem elsewhere. -f finds non-symlink files, but not directories. it doesn't seem possible to use -f and -d together.

Comment: Sure it is, just remove `-f` and then `find` will find both files and directories but not symlinks `:)`

Comment: i'm using `-e` and it seems to behave.

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this using `find + probe function`

```
prober()
{
find /path/to/dir2 -name "$1" -printf "%P\n"
}
export -f prober
find -H /path/to/dir1 -type f  -printf "%P" -exec bash -c 'prober "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: this seems promising, but it gives the find error about "warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do)"

Comment: i tried your changes, but it still gives the same error and doesn't seem to work